# Find zeros of this function:

Tags: functions, trigonometry

$$(3\tan(x)+4\cot(x))\cdot\sin(2x)$$
Do I have to multiply them and solve, or one by one, like:
$$(3\tan(x)+4\cot(x))=0$$and$$\sin(2x)=0.$$

Comment: The Maple command $$ with(RealDomain): [solve({(3*tan(x)+4*cot(x))*sin(2*x) = 0}, AllSolutions)]$$ outputs $[].$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that

if $\displaystyle(3\tan x+4\cot x)=0\implies 3\tan x+\frac4{\tan x}=0\iff3\tan^2x+4=0$ which is impossible for real $x$

If $\sin2x=0, 2x=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

If $n$ is even $=2m$(say) $2x=2m\pi, x=m\pi,\cot x=\cot m\pi=\frac{\cos m\pi}{\sin m\pi}=\frac{(-1)^m}0$ hence not finite

If $n$ is odd $=2m+1$(say) $2x=(2m+1)\pi, x=\frac{(2m+1)\pi}2,\tan x=\tan\frac{(2m+1)\pi}2=\frac{(-1)^m}0$ hence not finite

So, we don't have any real solution which will be more evident below

**Method** $1:$
On multiplication,

$\displaystyle(3\tan x+4\cot x)\sin2x=\left(3\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+4\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)2\sin x\cos x=6\sin^2x+8\cos^2x$

Using $\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1=1-2\sin^2A$

$6\sin^2x+8\cos^2x=3(1-\cos2x)+4(1+\cos2x)=7+\cos2x$

Do you know for real $y,-1\le \cos y\le 1$

**Method** $2:$

Using $\displaystyle\sin2A=\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}$ and $\displaystyle\cot x=\frac1{\tan x}$

$\displaystyle(3\tan x+4\cot x)\sin2x=\left(3t+\frac4t\right)\frac{2t}{1+t^2}=\frac{2(3t^2+4)}{1+t^2}$ where $t=\tan x$

Comment: When we get 7+cos(2x) and write this: 7+cos(2x)=0, then we get sin(x)=2. I don't get it xD

Comment: @A6Tech, As $-1\le\cos y\le1$ we can directly put $y=2x$. Again, $7+\cos2x=0\iff 7+1-2\sin^2x=0\iff \sin x=\pm2$  Again for real $x,-1\le \sin x\le1$

Comment: So this means y is never 0? No zeros?

Comment: @A6Tech, could you follow my method?

Comment: I could, but I don't understand. When cos2x=-7, then wolfram alpha gives this root: x=1/2(cos^-1(-7)+-2k*pi), k belongs to Z

Comment: @A6Tech, how to define $\cos^{-1}(-7)$

Comment: As far as I know, cos can't be -7. Max is 1, min is -1. I have no idea how it can be defined...

Comment: @A6Tech, it cannot be defined in the real values as $\cos2x=7\implies \sin2x=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^22x}=?$

Comment: Which means this function has unreal zeros? xD

Comment: @A6Tech, yes see at the first line $\tan^2x=-\frac43$ which is also available from $$7=\cos2x=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$$

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.

Comment: @A6Tech, my pleasure

Answer (score 2):

You can proceed either way, but to assure you that you can proceed as noted secondly, we know that 
$$ab = 0 \implies a = 0 \;\text{ or }\; b = 0\;\;\text{Not necessarily both equal to zero!}$$

So
$$(3\tan(x)+4\cot(x))\cdot \sin(2x) \implies (3\tan(x)+4\cot(x))=0\;\text{ or } \sin(2x)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Either way you should get the same answer because Mathematically the equations are still the same. Having said that, the way you've written down as one by one makes it a lot easier because identifying the zeros of a smaller expression is generally easier.

Answer (score 0):

Separating out the functions in trigonometric products is not always valid.  Note that $3\tan x + 4 \cot x$ is not continuous, which is a sign that you need to take care, because the product is not necessarily always defined.

Note also that knowing $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$ tells you that the discontinuities will cancel, and that there is an underlying continuous function.

In this case the "problem points" are not zeros of the continuous function, so the answer is the same whether the function is taken as defined or undefined at those points.

Note also that using the formula for $\sin 2x$ the product comes out as $6\sin^2x+8\cos^2x=6+2\cos^2x$, and since $0\leq \cos^2 x \leq 1$ the function is clearly strictly positive $(\geq 6)$ wherever it is defined.